# Warning: A component is changing an uncontrolled input of type undefined to be controlled

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm getting a warning:

> > Warning: A component is changing an uncontrolled input of type undefined to be controlled.

I get the right value in the input field, but it won't let me edit it.  I'm dynamically creating these fields in state triggered by a button click.

```
<input
  className={
    'event-title-input event-input event-main-input input' +
    dat.id
  }
  name={'title' + dat.id}
  value={this.state['title' + dat.id] || ''}
  onChange={this.handleChange}
  style={{ display: 'none' }}
/>

var outerState = this;

  this.state.data.forEach(function(element) {

    var stateTitle = "title" + element.id;
    var stateLocation = "location" + element.id;
    var stateDescription = "description" + element.id;
    var stateStartDate = "startdate" + element.id;
    var stateEndDate = "enddate" + element.id;

    outerState.setState({ [stateTitle]: element.title });
    outerState.setState({ [stateLocation]: element.location });
    outerState.setState({ [stateDescription]: element.description 
});
    outerState.setState({ [stateStartDate]: element.startdate });
    outerState.setState({ [stateEndDate]: element.enddate });
  });
  this.setState({ saveEdit: 'Save'});
```

Comment: Please post the full component?

Comment: Probably because your `input` tag doesn't have any `type` (e.g. `text`, `password` etc.).

Comment: vpulp, just tried that, no luck.

Comment: What's the handleChange function?

Answer (score 0):

If that is the whole component, you seem to be missing a `handleChange` function. It should probably look something like this:

```
handleChange(e, id) {
  this.setState({
    ['title' + id]: e.target.value
  });
}
```

After that, each input should call this function with an `id`, say:

```
<input onChange={e => this.handleChange(e, dat.id)} ... />
```

(I imagine the `<input>` code is inside some kind of mapping function, but in case you only have one input, it could be made in a more simple way).

Comment: Trying that solution... when I try to change/edit the value in the field (in the browser) I get this:

TypeError: Cannot read property 'setState' of undefined
handleChangeTitle
src/App.js:251
  };  
 handleChangeTitle(e) {
   this.setState({
     ['title' + 0]: e.target.value
});
}

Comment: Add: `this.handleChange = this.handleChange.bind(this)` in the constructor.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of repeatingly call setState you can just set the state at once when the data arrived:

```
this.setState(
  {
    saveEdit: 'Save',
    ...this.state.data.reduce(
      (result, element) => ({
        ...result,
        ...[
          'title',
          'location',
          'description',
          'startdate',
          'enddate',
        ].reduce((result, key) => {
          result[key + element.id] = element[key];
          return result;
        }, {}),
      }),
      {}
    ),
  },
  current =>
    console.log('current state is now:', current)
);
```

}

Are you sure every input defaults to an empty string (`value={this.state['title' + dat.id] || ''}`)if state is not set?

What does onChange look like?